# Sum values based on their string ID

Tags: r, string, sum

I have a data frame that consists of comma-separated sequences of strings. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(patterns = c("CCDC127, HSF1, NDUFB9", "CCDC127, EXOC3, YIF1A", "EXOC3, NDUFB9, YIF1A"))
df
               patterns
1 CCDC127, HSF1, NDUFB9
2 CCDC127, EXOC3, YIF1A
3  EXOC3, NDUFB9, YIF1A
```

I have another data frame, where each string corresponds to numerical value. For example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(strings = c("CCDC127", "HSF1", "NDUFB9", "EXOC3", "YIF1A"),
                   scores = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
df2
  strings scores
1 CCDC127     10
2    HSF1     11
3  NDUFB9     12
4   EXOC3     13
5   YIF1A     14
```

I would like to calculate a sum of each pattern from the first data frame based on values in the second data frame. For example:

```
patterns sum
1 CCDC127, HSF1, NDUFB9  33
2 CCDC127, EXOC3, YIF1A  37
3  EXOC3, NDUFB9, YIF1A  39
```

I would appreciate any directions and help with this question.

Thank you!
Olha

Comment: `rownames(df2) <- df2$strings;
sapply(strsplit(df$patterns, ", *"), function(p) sum(df2[p, "scores"]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` and `sapply` with `match`:

```r
df$sum <- sapply(strsplit(df$patterns, ", "), 
                 function(x) sum(df2$scores[match(x, df2$strings)]))
df
#>                patterns sum
#> 1 CCDC127, HSF1, NDUFB9  33
#> 2 CCDC127, EXOC3, YIF1A  37
#> 3  EXOC3, NDUFB9, YIF1A  39
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one where I'm sure there will be a super smart apply solution but I would do it by converting the `df` table into a lookup table, then joining it on and summarising.

```
df %>%
  mutate(patterns2 = patterns) %>%
  separate(patterns2, paste("c", 1:3)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = paste("c", 1:3)) %>%
  #end of lookup creation, now join on
  right_join(df2, by = c("value" = "strings" )) %>%
  group_by(patterns) %>%
  summarise(scores = sum(scores))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Convert df2 into a named list `L` suitable for use with `eval` and then evaluate each expression formed by parsing `pattern` after replacing comma with plus.

```
L <- with(df2, split(scores, strings))
transform(df, sums = sapply(parse(text = gsub(",", "+", patterns)), eval, L))
```

giving:

```
               patterns sums
1 CCDC127, HSF1, NDUFB9   33
2 CCDC127, EXOC3, YIF1A   37
3  EXOC3, NDUFB9, YIF1A   39
```

**2)** Another approach is to extract the words from patterns, look them up in L from (1) and then sum.

```
library(gsubfn)
transform(df, sums = sapply(strapply(patterns, "\\w+", x ~ L[[x]]), sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr::separate` and `rowSums`, all inside a `mutate` call:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df%>%mutate(
  sum = df %>% separate(col=patterns, sep=', +', into=paste0('pattern', 1:3))%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~df2$scores[df2$strings==.x]))%>%
  rowSums())

               patterns sum
1 CCDC127, HSF1, NDUFB9  33
2 CCDC127, EXOC3, YIF1A  37
3  EXOC3, NDUFB9, YIF1A  39
```